# jQuery `map` convert arrays in to `dom` element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I am looping a data, and creating a result using `map` method from `jQuery`. after the loop done, I am getting the result as `array` based `object` like this:

```
[jQuery.fn.init[1], jQuery.fn.init[1], jQuery.fn.init[1], jQuery.fn.init[1], jQuery.fn.init[1]]
```

But i require the `jQuery` based object (regular dom element) how can i get that from the `map` output?

I tried using `get()` after completing the loop. but throws `error`. what is the correct way to get the `dom` output?

Here is my function :

```
this.tbody = this.tableData.map(function (item, index) {
    tr = $('<tr />', { id: item.ID });
    tr.append('<td><input class="selectRow" type="checkbox" /></td>');
    that.headerNames.map(function (label) {
        var newlabel = label.replace(' ', '');
        var labelData = item[newlabel];
        tr.append('<td>' + labelData + '</td>');
    });
    console.log(tr); // [tr#66, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…] //i require all trs became a single output
    return tr;
});

console.log(this.tbody);
```

Comment: Isn't the `jQuery` based object also an array of such?

Comment: When i console, i can able to see the `element` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to return a dom object reference from the map handler then pass the array to jQuery and try

```
var tbody = this.tableData.map(function (item, index) {
    var tr = $('<tr />', {
        id: item.ID
    });
    tr.append('<td><input class="selectRow" type="checkbox" /></td>');
    that.headerNames.map(function (label) {
        var newlabel = label.replace(' ', '');
        var labelData = item[newlabel];
        tr.append('<td>' + labelData + '</td>');
    });
    console.log(tr); // [tr#66, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…] //i require all trs became a single output
    return tr.get(0);
});

this.tbody = $(tbody)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jsgnswzr/), [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jsgnswzr/2/)